# AutoCompleteextender in Ajax Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'd like to know if the AutoComplete Extender recognizes the white space as the first character. That is, the user begins by entering one white space in the textBox and the AutoComplete lists all the options stored in a table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it treats white space as character. I am saying it after checking [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx).

First I wrote `'abc'`(no preceding space) then I wrote `'  abc'`(with space) and results were same.